# MVVM design - handle common ViewModel for several views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my scenario I have lots of views (UserControls) that as part of it contain some filter options. Lets for example say that there are in total 10 filter options, but not all views show all 10 filter options. Some of them show only 3, some of them 8, etc. The important thing is that when one filter option is set on one view, all views that contain this filter option should have the same value.

```
AView: filterOption1, FilterOption2, FilterOption3
BView: filterOption1, FilterOption3, FilterOption5
CView: filterOption2, FilterOption4, FilterOption6, FilterOption7
```

When user sets on AView filterOption1 = True, the same value should be set on all views that use filterOption1 (ex BView). This led me to decision to have one CommonViewModel (singleton), that will contain common (shared) data, and that will expose all filter options in it, and that all views should bind to this CommonViewModel.

In order to display filter options for particular view, I can think of two approaches:

1) design ONE CommonView, create new instance for each representation, and hide the filter options where not needed

```
<DataTemplate DataType="vm:CommonViewModel">
  <vw:CommonView ShowFilterOption1="True" ShowFilterOption3="True" />
</DataTemplate>
```

2) Design separate view for each different representation (different filter options)

What do you think about these approaches, which one would you prefer, do you have some other ideas, and what would be the best choice to follow proper MVVM design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n views that bind to one viewmodel and once a property in viewmodel changes the views should update = binding twoways to that property

1) one view with all filter options means you will need custom logic for displaying only the filter options you wish to see. = binding to visibility

2) separate view for each different representation of filter option is also a possibility but i would do this only if futhermore each separate view contains some extra controls or logic which makes each separate view somehow unique else use 1).

Comment: The complexity that could arise from having one CommonView is how to layout the filter options. As I said, there are 7-8 filter options that are used on 20 views, but not all of them are used on all views. That means that I would need to have some complex layout handling in code, since I need to have something like a grid of fitler options, where rows / columns will be dynamically set.

Comment: yes my friend programming would make alot fun if we could just drag things together.. but its not the case and so in your example you will need to have a stackpanel or grid and to add uielements at runtime.. you will also need to hide your filteroptions and to show them when needed.. thats part of writing logic for your one view

Comment: My friend, I am not running from writing the code, that's the easiest part. Can you write anything about the disadvantages of these two methods, because from what you have written I did not get any info about why, most of the things you said are just how should I implement the methods that I named, which is not my question. The decision I make now will have a major impact on application, since more that 30 yiews will be affected by it, so I need to be 100% sure about the best method.

Comment: Its easy. 30 views + filteroptions = big memory impacts.. 1 view and you dynamically initalize what you need and you destroy what you dont need = very nice and clean memory footprints

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are advising to have 1 cached view for all 30 views? this is not possible... Imagine that I show two views in my application, that show different filter options? How would I set one view instance with 2 different representations?

Comment: are you asking me to implement that for you?

Comment: :) that's not possible to implement... I dont believe you understand the requirement...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26805/discussion-between-goran-and-hedgehog)

Answer (score 0):

To me, this kind of logic - whether to include a particular filterOption into a view or not, actually belongs to the view model, and not view.
I would consider implementing one view, and separate view model instances for each of A,B,C. The view model can be one class, which is parametrized by filterOptions it will show.

Comment: This mehtod would require to synchronize the values between each ViewModel. This will bring a lot of complexity to the project, there is a big possibility that some property can be left unsync. Maintenance price has jumped highly... Or you have some idea how to do this easily?

Comment: Regarding the "To me, this kind of logic actually belongs to the view model, and not view.". To my understanding, ViewModel deals with presentation logic and state, and it should not deal with what its visual representation will be like. In this case, I could have a filter on the view, or not. The ViewModel provides support (logic) for filtering, but whether some filters will be set or not, is something that is View's responsibility, to my opinion.

Comment: You can still have  the superset of all filer options in one place. Then you have another ViewMOdel class (maybe it's just a collection), which represent a subset of filters.

Comment: public class ScreenViewModel : INotify..
{
    public ScreenViewMOdel()
    {
       AllFilters = new ObservableCollection(GetAllFilters());
       AFilters = new ObservableCollection(new []
                   {
                     AllFilters[0], AllFilters[1]
                   }
                   );
    BFilters = //... include some other filter options
    CFilters =//..
    }

    ObservableCollection<Filter> AllFilters {get;set;}
    ObservableCollection<Filter> AFilters {get; set;}
    ObservableCollection<Filter> BFilters {get; set;}
}